# Blogger show current full URL in meta tags

Tags: facebook, web-crawler, blogger, sharing

I'm using my Blogger as a SPA site. And user are able to share posts to Facebook.
Each post are identical by ?id={posts_id} in the request URL, The {post_id} are parsed by Javascript, and find the posts from JSON data.

But Facebook sharing crawler is not support for SPA sites to read their og: tags. 
So, We need to use  to make Facebook Crawler to read og: tags from another URL.

I have tried many way to make Blogger response HTML  with the href="" contains full requested URL.

This is my try: The full URL is: www.abc.com/2016/07/31.html?id=1

```
    <link expr:href='data:blog.url' rel='opengraph'/> 
Will generate with HTML
    <link href='www.abc.com/2016/07/31.html' rel='opengraph'/>
```

Is there any way to make Blogger show full requested URL from HTML response code ?

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are utilizing the new themes released by Blogger (Refer to [this](https://blogger.googleblog.com/2017/03/share-your-unique-style-with-new.html)). Then you can use the following code to achieve what you require -

```
<b:if cond='data:view.isPost'>
    <link expr:href='data:blog.url + "?id=" + data:view.postId' rel='opengraph'/> 
</b:if>
```

This will generate the URL of the form -

```
www.abc.com/2016/07/post-title.html?id=PostID
```

The `PostID` will be the unique ID that Blogger assigns to each post. This will render only on the Post pages.

For making this work on static pages, add the following code as well to the template -

```
<b:if cond='data:view.isPage'>
    <link expr:href='data:blog.url + "?id=" + data:view.pageId' rel='opengraph'/> 
</b:if>
```

To fetch the data of the page content by utilizing the Page ID,send a request to the following endpoint -

```
https://www.blogger.com/feeds/BlogID/pages/default/PageID?alt=json
```

Replace `BlogID` and `PageID` with the actual values